# how does solr cloud merge results across multiple shards

Tags: solr, search-engine, solrcloud

As the title asked: how does solr cloud merge results across multiple shards
I thought the procedure as following, if I'm wrong please correct:
Randomly select any server to collect the result lists from every shard, then sort the lists by the first element(it should be the score). Pop up the first one and shift the rest elements in the queue, and heap sort again, then pop up. Finally the queue all empty, you get the merged result.